# Looking for a Collection of Examples and Counter Examples for Assumptions about the Properties of Planar Euclidean TSP Instances?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, examples, counterexamples

Where can I find example and counter examples to seemingly plausible assumption about the properties of optimal solutions of planar euclidean TSP instances?

The reason for asking is that the problem instances, that one finds on the internet, seem to almost exclusively come from some real-world problems and are lacking theoretical motivation; the only open problem being to find the optimal solution.

I would however like to have exemplary instances, that for e.g. demonstrate that an optimal tour may simultaneously contain the shortest and the longest edge, or, the longer diagonal of an empty, narrow rhombic region defined by four points of an TSP instance.

**Question:**
have there ever been attempts to collect optimal solutions of (small) planar euclidean TSP instances with unusual properties and, where could such collections be found?